Duplicate JSON Objects into list of JSON Objects using JOLT
My Input JSON is as below:
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "desc1": "test1",
    "desc2": "test2",
    "desc3": "test3"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value11",
    "key2": "value22",
    "desc1": "test11",
    "desc3": "test33"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value111",
    "key2": "value222",
    "desc2": null  
  }
]

I want to map "desc1", "desc2" and "desc3" to "desc" and copy/duplicate the the parent JSON object such that my output looks as  below. Please note that desc1, desc2 and desc3 may be present or not present or the corresponding values can be null as well
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "desc": "test1"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "desc": "test2"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "desc": "test3"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value11",
    "key2": "value22",
    "desc": "test11"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value11",
    "key2": "value22",
    "desc": "test33"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value111",
    "key2": "value222"
  }
]

Can anyone please let me know what specification should be used for this purpose. I tried various options present in this for but to no avail.

You should loop through each individual desc attributes such as
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "~desc*": "NuLL" //set as literal "NuLL" whenever the value is null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "desc*": {
          "*": {//non-NuLL valued attributes 
            "@2": {//transferred from the level of "desc*"
              "key*": "&4_&2.&",//attributes those start with "key"
              "$1": "&4_&2.desc"//attributes those start with "desc"
            }
          },
          "NuLL": {//NuLL valued attributes 
            "@2": {
              "key*": "&4_&2.&",
              "": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Much thanks for the answer, if  value of "desc1", "desc2" or "desc3" is null, we do not want "desc" to be part of output Json, but the rest of the key values should remain
Also even of "desc1", "desc2" or "desc3" are not present, then the rest of key-values should still be part of output JSON
Would that be possible?

Hi @ShashiKiranGM , nice to help, but sorry that I missed that part, and just fixed it.

Hi @Barbaros, Much thanks for the help.  It is working.
